# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined offset: 1

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel,Here I am trying to make a simple registration and login form, Before registration and login form was working fine. But when I decided to put validation in `name`, `email` and `password` it is giving me this error,Any help would be appreciated...
Thanks

> "Undefined offset: 1"

**HTML**

```php
@extends("layouts.master")

@section('title')
  My page
@endsection

@section('content')

  @if(count($errors)>0)
    <div class ="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
          @foreach($errors->all()as $error)
            <li>{{"$error"}}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endif



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Sign-Up</h3>
      <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Your email</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input class="form-control"  type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

        <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary">sumbit</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Login </h3>
      <form action="{{route('signin')}}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Your email</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input class="form-control"  type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>

        <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary">sumbit</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\UserTypes;

use Auth;
use Hashids;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hash;


class UserController extends controller
{
    public function getdashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);

        $email = $request->email;
        $first_name = $request->first_name;
        $password = bcrypt($request->password);


        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could paste the whole error, that would be easier to help.

Comment: @Tharaka Dilshan error is that much only and showing this bunch of code and it is highlighted on this  $iteratee = trim($matches[1]);